# problame with adding custom webparts to my Sharepoint tenant

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, gulp, web-parts

I'm a new Sharepoint global admin and I've found a webpart on github I would really like to use.

However, I have no experience at all in git/json PowerShell etc and all i know right now is how to connect my Sharepoint tenant to PowerShell.

I would really like to add those webparts: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-solutions/tree/master/solutions/ModernSearch

and I've followed the instruction in this page: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-solutions to use the solutions:

- I've cloned the project.
- I've cd to the right folder (ModernSearch)
- run npm install
- and when I'm trying to run `gulp serve` I get an message "No gulpfile found"

Any idea what I can do to fix this and upload those webparts to my Sharepoint tenant?

I've also downloaded node.js and connected to my tenant via PowerShell (`connect-sposervice`) before I tried to run those commands mentioned above.

Sorry for lack of knowledge, would really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

cd to spfx folder as gulp.js hosts in spfx folder.

Go to the spfx directory

In the command line run:

- npm install
- gulp serve

Comment: you mean cd to this folder: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-solutions/tree/master/solutions/ModernSearch/react-search-refiners-renderer and than run those commands? ive tried this but the gulp serve got stuck in the middle of the proccess.
i did connected to my spo-service (my tenant) before i ran those commands - is this how powershall knows on what tenant to download those webparts? or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you installed nodejs? Above two commands doesn't matter you connected to your tenant or not, just build&run the SPFx solution(it'll start nodejs web temp server to run this SPFx solution.).

Comment: i did manage to run the commands but the gulp serve command just opened my tenant spo workstation and stops there..any idea what may cause this problem? ty!